# why does tapply() show me entries that i filtered out?

Tags: r

I have taken the iris data.frame and then filtered out the "setosa" from the species.

when i do `tapply()`, it gives me a summary of all 3 things that were originally in that column.  why does it show me setosa as NA. It shouldnt know about setosa!!!

```
library(dplyr)
a <-filter(iris, Species != "setosa")

tapply(a$Sepal.Length, a$Species, mean)
```

Result:

```
    tapply(a$Sepal.Length, a$Species, mean)   
 #  setosa versicolor  virginica    
 #      NA      5.936      6.588
```

what am i missing?

Comment: most likely its because Species is a factor. Even if you remove all cases within one factor-realisation, the factorvariable still knows it has 3 different realisations. droplevels() should solve this hopefully

Comment: @TinglTanglBob is right, this would get rid of it : `tapply(a$Sepal.Length,as.character( a$Species), mean)`

Answer (score 3):

That's because in your filtered dataframe, the column `Species` is still a factor with 3 levels, even if there are only 2 of them in the column. You can use `droplevels` to drop the unused levels:

```
library(dplyr) 
a <- droplevels(filter(iris, Species != "setosa"))
tapply(a$Sepal.Length, a$Species, mean)
# versicolor  virginica 
#      5.936      6.588
```

Comment: No need for dplyr, use `subset` or `[`.

Comment: Regarding the approach of OP i think using dplyr here is the best way to keep the answer as close as possible to the question. Using other subset methods might cause unintended confusion i fear.